# pause build and start another build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to implement continuous integration using Jenkins and i came across below scenario.

> I have a build, say Build A which is configured to run every 1 hour. This job require another process ( independant background java process ). But what happens is sometimes this background job will not respond or we have to restart the job in order to complete the Build A without any exceptions. If the process is down, we will get console exceptions and build will fail.

I have found a solution for this.

> Abort the current Build A and start Build B. 
>   Trigger Build A after build B is success.

But

> What i am looking for is, if there is a console exception, pause this build and trigger Build B which will restart the process and I should be able to resume Build A when the build B is success.

Comment: Are you on a *nix machine or windows?

Comment: We are using unix box.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way known to do that in Jenkins. It would be much easier to start (and possibly restart) the fixture process from the build itself. Perhaps even integrate it into your build/test tool so the CI job can be easily replicated or reproduced locally.